# Python Selenium: Iterating through a dynamic element

Tags: python, selenium, loops, dynamic

I'm sure that this has probably been asked before, but I have yet to encounter it. My apologies if it is already up here. However, I'm having an issue trying to figure the logic out: The page begins with a list of elements (20 to begin) I'm looking to click. After a scroll, more of the same elements are displayed. I'm having an issue getting to interact with loaded elements after the scroll. This is what I've come up with so far:

```
def clix():
chazz = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("button[class^='message-anywhere']")
for x in chazz:
    if x.is_displayed():
            x.click()
            time.sleep(1)
            driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button[data-control-name^='overlay.close']").click()
            time.sleep(2)

scrollz()
def scrollz():
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(4)
    clix()
clix()
```

I know this isn't as 'pythonic' or 'best practices' as it should be. I'm simply worried about functionality. Any insight would be much appreciated. The 
            `driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button[data-control-name^='overlay.close']").click()` button is only to x out a pop up window.

Thanks

html:

```
<button class="message-anywhere-button artdeco-button artdeco-button--secondary artdeco-button--2" aria-label="Send message to Abarna Rajkumar" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-63="63">
    Chat
</button>
```

Comment: Could you post some HTML for the page you are trying to automate, including the elements you are locating in this test? This will help anyone trying to answer solve your issue more efficiently.

Comment: I added the html of the button. Identifying the button hasn't been the problem. The script just gets lost in where it is in the indexing once further elements are loaded, and I don't know how to write the logic for that.

Answer (score 1):

I think Only one function can resolve your problem.I might wrong since I don't have application under test.

- Induce `WebDiverWait` And wait for `visibility_of_all_elements_located`()
- While iterating use `location_once_scrolled_into_view` and then click.
- Induce `WebDiverWait` And wait for `element_to_be_clickable`() to click the close button

---

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

def clix():
 chazz =WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"button[class^='message-anywhere']")))
 for x in range(len(chazz)):
    chazz = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[class^='message-anywhere']")))
    chazz[x].location_once_scrolled_into_view
    chazz[x].click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"button[data-control-name^='overlay.close']"))).click()

clix()
```

Answer (score 0):

chazz = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("button[class^='message-anywhere']")
global xx
xx = 0
def clix():
    global xx
    print (xx)
    chazz = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("button[class^='message-anywhere']")
    while xx < len(chazz):
        print(xx)

```
    chazz[xx].click()
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button[data-control-name^='overlay.close']").click()
    time.sleep(1)

    xx = xx+1

driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);")
xx = xx+1
```

i = 0

```
while i < 1000:
    clix()
```

and if I truly wanted to run it into infinity... I'd just set the while loop to something unachievable.... while i < -1 ... fox example.